# How do I update my Master UITableview after I have added contents to it?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am working on a Master-view application on Swift. The app has to view controllers; detailView where user's input is accepted and Master view where cells containing the info are supposed to be. Like a contacts app.

I have done everything and the app works fine, however I have not been able to display my content on the Main Screen (master view). The data from user is safely stored in array in a different class. Here is a bit of code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let object = contact.entries[indexPath.row] as ContactListEntry
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.firstName + " " + object.lastName
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object.phoneNumber!

        return cell

    }
```

I need to be able to display the cell with its contents on the Master view.
Please let me know if it doesn't make sense. I can clarify a bit more.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it that your master view cells aren't displaying at all? Or that they're not updating after you go back from the detail view?

Comment: @Ollie think the latter. How do I go about it? I thought of calling a refresh control but am not sure where to do it.

Comment: I mean how do I update the view once I have added elements to the cell.

Comment: If you update the `contact.entries` dataSource, you can then call reloadData on the tableView. This will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again and you can update the cells. Is this what you mean? Or is updating the `contact.entries` from the detailView the issue?

Comment: Add a delegate to Details View which points to Master View. Whenever data gets updated in Details View call a method to notify Master View in which you could reload table data.

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: thanks guys, will work on your advices. Much appreciated